# When can I stop picking up trash?

Tags: professor-layton-the-last-specter, professor-laytons-london-life

I started playing *[Professor Layton's London Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professor_Layton_and_the_Last_Specter#Professor_Layton.27s_London_Life)* today, and while my job as a Trash Picker is pretty profitable, I would love to be able to do something different. I know that in the Station, a man mentioned that if I was a Bus Driver of a certain level I could apply to be a Ticket Taker, so I know there are other jobs out there. How do I go about getting a better job?

Comment: You should probably start with a strong a resume as possible.

Comment: Just a note after picking up lots of trash, you never need to leave the main town screen. i.e. you don't need to go to the docks or to Sasha park in order to complete your trash collecting routine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to keep picking up the trash (make sure you pick up every piece, the game will let you know when you have finished), and eventually you will move up in rank enough to be offered a job as a Taxi Driver - from there, you can get other jobs as you rank up in previous ones (with the exception of some you need to discover, like the job in the hotel delivering luggage, and juggling for the girl in the park.)